# Is it safe to give 5v through 5v pin of arduino uno r3 while usb cable inserted

Tags: arduino, esc

Is it safe to give 5v through 5v pin of arduino uno r3 while the USB cable is inserted? I have ESCs connected to it which aren't likely to start in other cases. The 5v and gnd is coming from the BEC circuit of a connected ESC. Please help me. Thanks[image]

Comment: yes i supply 5v from esc to arduino

Comment: Cause i am making quadcopter so escs are used which provide 5v output.

Comment: any problem can happen with that?

Comment: Chuck, Bilal isn't talking about the ESC's PWM output (its motor drive), but about a 5V Aux Out on the ESC, or a 5V BEC (battery eliminator circuit) on the ESC.  The comments in your answer about not connecting to an ESC may be irrelevant.

Comment: what are you saying. i dont get it

Comment: Take a look here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/896 .  Basically what's going to happen is that you will be putting the USB and the ESC 5V supplies in parallel.  This can be OK but it's hard to know for sure.  It's better to power the Arduino with higher voltage through its VIN pin.  The 5V pin was intended to be used as output so while you could power the board through it they advise not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It should be completely safe. Assuming that the 5V BEC on the ESC is not damaged then it *is* providing a regulated voltage to your Arduino. Furthermore, the USB port on the Arduino is protected from back current with Zener diodes, thus protecting whatever may be plugged into that port.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/65582/76598) to similar question on the EE Stack Exchange:

> The [official stance on supplying power](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno) directly to the 5V pin on the Arduino Uno is thus:
>
> > Supplying voltage via the 5V or 3.3V pins bypasses the regulator, and can damage your board. We don't advise it.

Comment: the 5v can support input on 5v pin as well as output 5v when other supply is connected. i think you are confusing in thins

Comment: the esc.s power the motor but for motors they have other two wires, red and black color larger crosssection wires. i am not using them, i am getting the 5v power,. this 5v is not given to motors

Comment: that is it now?

Comment: Most ESC's have a BEC. The OP is really talking about providing power to the Arduino via the 5V BEC circuit included in the ESC circuitry. Everything after the EDIT is irrelevant. Also, the BEC is another *regulated* 5V source, so it should be safe.

Comment: @Octopus - I understand what you're saying. I couldn't tell from OP's post how everything was connected. The statement "I have esc,s connected to it which arnt likely to start in other cases"  made it seem to me like OP was trying to somehow use USB power for the ESC, but then I thought OP was trying to connect ESC output or the battery directly to the 5V port, and none of those cases would work.

Answer (score 0):

please see: https://dronesandrovs.wordpress.com/?attachment_id=241#main

It looks like it's safe.

Comment: Can you summarize the important parts from the link? Links tend to rot.